# Look for several values in several value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Here is the rather particular problem :

```
 id |   column_num   |
 ---|----------------|
   1|  5,12,64,7,78  |
   2|  5,53,7,6      |
   3|  94,78,32,27   |
```

I need to find lines having the values : 12, 7, 78

I need to look for several values corresponding to a cell SQL.
I use MySQL. You have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: Oops... Don't store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: is column_num varchar()?

Comment: you will find plenty of identical questions here in the last few days... have you made any little search before posting?

Comment: Do you need to have all three values in the string or at least one to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers.
I have to find a solution via the function [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) by curling with the PHP.

```
$_POST['test_ids'] = [12,7,78];

if (!empty($_POST['test_ids'])) {
    $filter .= ' AND (';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['test_ids'] as $id) {
        $filter .= ($i > 0) ? ' OR ' : '';
        $filter .= ' FIND_IN_SET(\'' . $id . '\', column_num) ';
        $i++;
    }
    $filter .= ') ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have come out the solution and hope this will help you.

> Note: You may normalize the query by yourself as I just share my
>   concept on this problem.

Query as below :-

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    id int,
    column_num varchar (max)
) 

INSERT INTO table1 (id, column_num) VALUES
(1, '5,12,64,7,78'),
(2, '5,53,7,6'),
(3, '94,78,32,27'),
(4, '1,74,32,12,78')

CREATE VIEW vSeperate_Num AS
WITH tmp(id, num, column_num) AS
(
    SELECT id, LEFT(column_num, CHARINDEX(',',column_num+',')-1), STUFF(column_num, 1, CHARINDEX(',',column_num+','), '')
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, LEFT(column_num, CHARINDEX(',',column_num+',')-1), STUFF(column_num, 1, CHARINDEX(',',column_num+','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE column_num > ''
)
SELECT id, num
FROM tmp

;WITH Contain_Selected_Num AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, num
        FROM vSeperate_Num
    ) AS pvt
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(num)
        FOR num IN ( [12], [7], [78] )
    ) AS pvt
)
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM Contain_Selected_Num
    WHERE [12] > 0 AND [7] > 0 AND [78] > 0
)
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: This wont be unique, because `%7%` would also match `1,74,32`

Comment: Hi @PhillipD, I agreed with you. I have updated my idea on this problem, hope we can cross check together. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

At least one to match, try:

```
select * From table_name where 
column_num = '12' or column_num like '%,12,%' or column_num like '%,12' or column_num like '12,%'
union 
select * From table_name where 
column_num = '7' or column_num like '%,7,%' or column_num like '%,7' or column_num like '7,%'
union 
select * From table_name where 
column_num = '78' or column_num like '%,78,%' or column_num like '%,78' or column_num like '78,%'
```

Have all three values, try this SQL:

```
select * From table_name where (column_num = '12' or column_num like '%,12,%' or column_num like '%,12' or column_num like '12,%')
and (column_num = '7' or column_num like '%,7,%' or column_num like '%,7' or column_num like '7,%')
and (column_num = '78' or column_num like '%,78,%' or column_num like '%,78' or column_num like '78,%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

Add a `,` to the start and end of each string, i.e. 5,12,64,7,78 -> ,5,12,64,7,78,

Then you can apply MySQL's `locate()` function for every number.

```
select id, column_num from (
select id, column_num,
       locate(',12,', column_num) as m12, 
       locate(',7,', column_num) as m7, 
       locate(',78,', column_num) as m78 
from your_table
) a
where m12 > 0 and m7 > 0 and m78 > 0;
```

If a particular number is not in the string, the result of locate will be 0, otherwise it will be the position in the string. In an outer query you can then check for this in a `where` statement.

The `where` statement can easily be adjusted according to your need, e.g. if you need a match of all three numbers or at least one.